# Kendo Scatter Chart - Reverse Dates in xAxis?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

I'm building a page with a Kendo scatter chart of data over time. The only catch is that the client wants the most recent data to the left. I've sorted the input datasource by date descending, but that seems to be blithely ignored, with the chart stubbornly plotting the data with dates ascending to the right.

Am I missing something, or is this simply unsupported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the reverse property on the xAxis to true:

```
xAxis: {
    reverse: true
},
```

> **[API Doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-xAxis.reverse)**

Comment: That is the answer and should be marked as an answer.

Comment: I knew I was missing something! Thanks!